# Graphics Not Updating in MapView from ViewModel GraphicsOverlay

Tags: wpf, arcgis

I am developing an application with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .Net and following the MVVM Pattern, in my ViewModel I have an ObservableCollection of GraphicsOverlay that I have binded to the MapView in my View, now when I add a new GraphicsOverlay to the ObservableCollection and add Graphics in it, graphics are not reflection in the View,

I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and all other things are working fine with the ViewModel

```
public class MapViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
private Map map;

public Map Map
{
get { return this.map; }
set { this.map = value; }
}
public ObservableCollection<GraphicsOverlay> GraphicsOverlays { get; set; }



public MapViewModel()
{
GraphicsOverlays = new ObservableCollection<GraphicsOverlay>();
}
```

And in my Method that is called by any event

```
public void UpdateMarker(MapPoint point)
{
GraphicsOverlays[0].Graphics.Clear();

// Create a symbol to symbolize the point
SimpleMarkerSymbol symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbolStyle.X, System.Drawing.Color.Yellow, 20);

// Create the graphic
Graphic symbolGraphic = new Graphic(point, symbol);

// Add the graphic to the graphics overlay
var newGraphicsOverlay=new GraphicsOverlay(); 
GraphicsOverlays[0].Graphics.Add(symbolGraphic);

}
```

And in my View I have

```
<esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView" Grid.Column="0" DataContext=" 
{StaticResource MapVM}" GraphicsOverlays="{Binding GraphicsOverlays}" Map=" 
{Binding Map}" Cursor="{Binding MapViewCursor}">
```

I am unable to find any sample that does exactly this, so how to do this, I am new to arcGIS, Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have updated the UpdateMarker Method like this

```
 public void UpdateMarker(MapPoint point)
    {
        GraphicsOverlays[0].Graphics.Clear();

        // Create a symbol to symbolize the point
        SimpleMarkerSymbol symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbolStyle.X, System.Drawing.Color.Yellow, 20);

        // Create the graphic
        Graphic symbolGraphic = new Graphic(point, symbol);
        // Add the graphic to the graphics overlay
        var newGraphicsOverlay = new GraphicsOverlay();
        newGraphicsOverlay.Graphics.Add(symbolGraphic);
        GraphicsOverlays[0] = newGraphicsOverlay;
    }
```

But still the symbol is not showing on the map.

Comment: Is the `GraphicsOverlay.Graphics` property an ObservableCollection? Otherwise you would have to replace `GraphicsOverlays[0]` with a new GraphicsOverlay (which you apparently already create but never use).

Comment: @Clemens no the GraphicsOverlay.Graphics is not an ObservableCollection, let me try with the new GraphicsOverlay.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a GraphicsOverlayCollection instead of an ObservableCollection as MapView.GraphicOverlays is a GraphicsOverlayCollection and not an ObservableCollection. Something like

```
public GraphicsOverlayCollection<GraphicsOverlay> GraphicsOverlays { get; set; }
```